# How to create a ubuntu bootable USB to run on Windows using a MAC

Tags: usb, windows, mac

How can I create an Ubuntu bootable USB to boot on a Windows 10, using a MAC running El Capitan? I tried using Unetbootin running on Mac (El Capitan), however my USB is not recognized! Also tried Disk Utility with no success. How to do it?

Comment: Use `sudo dd`. Be extra careful to specify the right block device, or else REALLY bad things **will** happen.

Answer (score 0):

First make absolutely sure that the USB key is not mounted (if it is, unmount it).  Next you should use

```
sudo diskutil list
```

To see if the USB key shows up.  If it does, then the "problem" is that it isn't formatted.  This is not actually a problem, you can proceed to use it.

If the USB key does not show up, there may be driver or hardware problems.  In either case, it's probably simplest to buy a new, working USB key.

Once you have a working identified USB key you can use a command like

```
sudo dd if=./xbmc-9.11-live-repack.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk<NUM> bs=1m
```

where  is the number of the disk that diskutil shows you.  Be very careful not to use one of your other disks where you might cause damage.

Here's a [blog posting with a more extensive explanation of the procedure](http://borgstrom.ca/2010/10/14/os-x-bootable-usb.html)

Comment: I assume by "boot on a Windows 10" the original poster means "boot on a PC" and not boot inside a virtual machine.  Can't comment to the question yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering, why insist on creating the stick with the Mac, when it's probably just a couple of minutes to do it in W10? Or did it fail on the W10 machine too?

If El Capitan refuses to give you access to the stick, a long shot is to install a VM and install Linux on the Mac and try from there.

Edit: A friend of mine reported problems with an El Capitan upgrade. So I ran into the following website to activate USB ports after the upgrade. Perhaps that helps.
http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/306777-guide-usb-fix-el-capitan-1011/